# Why isn't SYSDATETIME() changing on each call?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to analyze the performance of a query.  Unfortunately I don't have rights to run estimated or actual query plan against the database I'm reading.  (`SHOWPLAN` permission denied in database)

I've rewritten the original query, but would like to compare the execution times for the original query and my two queries.  To accomplish this I thought I would create 4 datetime2 variables, and record `SYSDATETIME()` between each iteration, then find the difference.

Unfortunately, I'm finding that once called, `SYSDATETIME()` does not update.

In total, my 3 queries run 17 seconds.  Between each execution, I should be able to see the time stamp change, but the variables are recording the same timestamp each time.

```
declare @a datetime2, @b datetime2, @c datetime2, @d datetime2

set @a = SYSDATETIME()

select bunch of columns from a bunch of joined tables

set @b = SYSDATETIME()

select bunch of columns and sub-queries from a bunch of tables joined a little differently

set @c = SYSDATETIME()

select bunch of columns and sub-queries from a bunch of differently joined tables and sub-queries

set @d = SYSDATETIME()

print @a
print @b
print @c
print @d
```

All 4 variable have the same value.

```
a   2019-04-05 16:00:09.3947421 
b   2019-04-05 16:00:09.3947421 
c   2019-04-05 16:00:09.3947421 
d   2019-04-05 16:00:09.3947421
```

Total execution time was 19 seconds, so there should have been valid data to review.

Any suggestions?

Comment: provide a repro of this. No repro here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0983ab7fb8ec0b78230323adecf8a82

Comment: Could be SQL parallelized and executed your queries out of order?

Comment: @Clay. no. parallelism in Sql Server doesnt work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, rather than burn anymore cycles worrying about it, I just printed the time stamp, and put a GO between each iteration of my tests.  Then did the math later.

Still don't know why SYSDATETIME isn't returning a true value with each call.  Maybe SQL server is trying to be helpful.

FYI, from this rtrim(ltrim(FIELD))) is quicker than FIELD like 'A%', which is quicker than FIELD = 'A' when FIELD is char(10).

Answer (score -1):

The entire query is probably started all at once.

Try running each query in separate batches instead. That should give you some useful timestamps.

```
declare @a datetime2 = SYSDATETIME()
print @a

go

select bunch of columns from a bunch of joined tables
declare @b datetime2 = SYSDATETIME()
print @b

go

select bunch of columns and sub-queries from a bunch of tables joined a little differently
DECLARE @c datetime2 = SYSDATETIME()
print @c

go

select bunch of columns and sub-queries from a bunch of differently joined tables and sub-queries
declare @d datetime2 = SYSDATETIME()
print @d

go
```

Comment: SQL Server does not execute different statements in the same batch simultaneously. Only one statement can run at a time. Probably the OP has made some error not shown in the code they have supplied to us. (like leaving a statement in there that assigns to all the variables in a single statement)

Comment: No, I've not left any thing out, and I'm not assigning all variable the same values at once. I have been doing SQL for over a decade.

Comment: That's what I had to do Peter, thanks.  But doesn't explain why SQL can't be bothered to return a true value each time the function is called.